# Chrome extension restart background script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension manifest V3 and in some situations the popup script can't connect to background script... I mean:

```
return chrome.runtime.sendMessage({}); //returns an error when called sometimes from popup
```

The first line of code in background script is to `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleAction);`
and absolutelly nowhere in the code is called to remove listener, so I am assuming that the code has a bug in some point that makes background script crash and the listener die by itself.
I'vent been able to track it yet, as there are no error messages in the log, so i want to make a quick workaround for the meantime i can't find the bug

Is it possible (somehow) to restart the background script from the popup script?

Comment: No, but you can reload the entire extension via chrome.runtime.reload() in the popup, which will reload everything, but it'll break the content scripts, see [this topic](/q/10994324) for more info.